# Caching an expensive to compute result in a class instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Lets say I've got something like the following

```
class C a where
  f :: a -> Text

newtype T a = T a

expensiveFunction :: (Bounded a, Enum a, ToText a) => Map a Text
expensiveFunction = _ 

cheapFunction :: (Bounded a, Enum a, ToText a) => T a -> Map a Text -> Text
cheapFunction = _

instance (Bounded a, Enum a, ToText a) => C (T a) where
  f x = cheapFunction x expensiveFunction
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
newtype U = U Int
  deriving C via (T Int)
```

Here's the problem I see. `expensiveFunction` will be called on each call to `f`. Which is bad.

I did have this thought, of changing the `T a` instance to:

```
instance (Bounded a, Enum a, ToText a) => C (T a) where
  f = flip cheapFunction expensiveFunction
```

And then hoping that `f` (i.e. the function of one argument) is computed once, which hopefully means that `expensiveFunction` is only computed once.

But I'm not sure how reliable this is. I'm guessing that probably won't work if the instance requested is polymorphic, but if the instance is monomorphic (i.e. `T Int` above) then I was hoping this would do the trick.

But `f` isn't an ordinary function, it's a instance function, and since `f` is defined in the class `C` as a function, not a stand alone value, perhaps it will be treated like a function and recompute each time.

Any thoughts? Is there a better approach I should be using here. I'd like to keep the nice deriving via syntax if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some quick experiments. Your suggestion of using `flip` to move `expensiveFunction` outside the final application of `f` seems to work quite well.

Here's what I used:

```
module Main where

import C
import U

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "f @(T Int)"
  let a = f (T @Int 1)
      b = f (T @Int 2)
      c = f (T @Int 3)
  a `seq` b `seq` c `seq` print [a, b, c]

  putStrLn "\n\nU"
  let x = f (U 4)
      y = f (U 5)
      z = f (U 6)
  x `seq` y `seq` z `seq` print [x, y, z]

  putStrLn "\n\ng @(T Int)"
  let g = f @(T Int)
      i = g (T 7)
      j = g (T 8)
      k = g (T 9)
  i `seq` j `seq` k `seq` print [i, j, k]
```

```
module C
  ( C (..)
  , T (..)
  , ToText (..)
  , expensiveFunction
  , cheapFunction
  )
where


import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Text qualified as Text

import Debug.Trace (trace)


class ToText a where
  toText :: a -> Text
  default toText :: Show a => a -> Text
  toText = Text.pack . show


instance ToText Int


class C a where
  f :: a -> Text

newtype T a = T a

expensiveFunction :: (Bounded a, Enum a, ToText a, Ord a) => Map a Text
expensiveFunction = trace "expensive" $ mempty

cheapFunction :: (Bounded a, Enum a, ToText a) => T a -> Map a Text -> Text
cheapFunction (T x) !_ = trace "cheap" $ toText x

instance (Bounded a, Enum a, ToText a, Ord a) => C (T a) where
  f = flip cheapFunction expensiveFunction
```

```
module U
  ( U (..)
  )
where

import C

newtype U = U Int
  deriving C via (T Int)
```

Without optimisations I get this:

```
f @(T Int)
expensive
cheap
expensive
cheap
expensive
cheap
["1","2","3"]


f @U
expensive
cheap
cheap
cheap
["4","5","6"]


g
expensive
cheap
cheap
cheap
["7","8","9"]
```

So as you thought, a polymorphic instance like the one for `T` re-evaluates `expensiveFunction` each time (because `f` is a function of the dictionaries for `Bounded a`, etc, and the evaluation of `expensiveFunction` occurs inside the application of `f` to the instance dictionaries even though it's outside the application of `f` to its final argument).

But the `f` for `U` is able to hold on to a single shared `expensiveFunction`, so it's only evaluated once even without any optimisations.

And as shown with `g`, you can always define a monomorphic variant, which will then ensure that `expensiveFunction` is shared across all uses of the monomorphic variant.

When compiling **with** optimisations I get this:

```
f @(T Int)
expensive
cheap
cheap
cheap
["1","2","3"]


f @U
cheap
cheap
cheap
["4","5","6"]


g
cheap
cheap
cheap
["7","8","9"]
```

The compiler has noticed that all of these are ultimately using `expensiveFunction @Int`, and shared it even across the instances for the different newtypes.

With optimisations, I get this behaviour even without applying your `flip` optimisation.

Personally, I would be willing to rely on the sharing of `expensiveFunction` across `f @U` calls (and `g` calls) in the unoptimised version. It conforms to what I would expect from a fairly naive mental model where sharing is determined by let-binding and scopes, so I consider it fairly unlikely that perturbations from changing the implementations or from future compiler versions would perform worse than this. So if sharing in monomorphic instances like `C U` and monomorphic wrappers like `g` is enough, then I'd just apply your `flip` optimisation and be content.

I'd be a little less comfortable relying on the precise behaviour of the optimisations; they're probably affected by how much the compiler decides to inline, which can easily change in future compiler versions or as I make changes to the code. So if sharing across all the instances (and even for polymorphic instances like `C (T a)`) is critical, then I'd want to think about writing less "nice" code that makes the sharing more explicit. But if this extra sharing is simply a nice performance boost that is not mission-critical, then no need to worry too much.